# Что нужно пушить на гит из файлов, над которыми ты работал и которые появились в результате работы фреймворка?

Tags: git, github

Написал простенький блог на Django, однако файлов в результате самого фреймворка достаточно много, а работал я лишь над несколькими файлами. Мне пушить весь проект? Или те, что я отправил. Я искал в гитхабе примеры, у них у всех отличается. Спасибо заранее. Вот мой git(я запушил туда абсолютно всё):https://github.com/OrazovTairlan/DjangoApp
Можете дать рекомендации? Относительно того, пушить все файлы или нет.

Comment: Пушить нужно то, что не может быть автоматически сгенерировано из других файлов. py-файлы, po-файлы — нужно, pycache, mo — не нужно

Comment: db.sqlite3 — НИ В КОЕМ СЛУЧАЕ КАТЕГОРИЧЕСКИ НЕ НУЖНО, там же ваши пароли хранятся

Comment: media — тоже не нужно, потому что это не сама программа, а результат работы программы, которому на гиту делать нечего

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я как понял, нужно пушить лишь те файлы, над которыми ты работал? Хоть даже без других файлов они работать не будут?

Comment: Если без какого-то файла работать не будет (или будет, но неправильно) — значит этот файл нужен

Comment: Коллекция гитигноров для разных языков https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: Благодарю еще раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала можно поступать так - пушить те файлы, без которых проект не запустится на новом компьютере. Все файлы, которые генерятся системой при установке проекта, а также файлы с паролями, конечно же, пушить не нужно.